# Process to gather raster cells under features

Tags: arcobjects, raster, features

I need to gather individual raster cells underneath a feature in a featureclass as quickly as possible. It seems that most ArcObjects functions have problem with island polygons, multi-part polygons, etc... and I would like to try and correct this in my own function.

The Geoprocess PolygonToRaster is VERY fast, and I would like to "mimic" what that is doing. Does anyone know of what that geoprocess may be doing on the backend that I could hopefully tap into?